# How to set specific image from wordpress post to Solilquy slider

Tags: wordpress, slider, wordpress-shortcode

I am trying to set a slider dynamically from my posts featured images and i am using Solilquy Plugin for it and i have 3 featured image in every post as you can see on the image i attached, it takes the Featured Image 1 for the slider but i want the Featured Image 3 [Banner News]. i have been searching for a solution or another plugin but couldn't find any.
Thank you.

[image]